# Recursion of an Integral

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let :

\begin{equation}y_n := \int_0^1{\frac{t^n}{t+5}dt}\end{equation}

I have to proof the following recursion:

$y_n = \frac{1}{5(n+1)} - \frac{1}{5}y_{n+1}$

I've already tried many things as to make $t^n = t\cdot t^{n-1}$, taking $u=1/(t+5)$ and other stuff but nothing seems to work...I can't get to the recursion form.

I don't need the answer right away but if you could point me in the right direction that'd be nice.

Comment: Hint: $t^{n+1} = t^n (t + 5 - 5)$

Comment: @Gribouillis: I was about to write a hinting answer along these lines. You should do this since you mentioned the idea first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y_n = \frac{1}{5(n+1)} - \frac{1}{5}y_{n+1}$$

Since $\int_{0}^{1} t^ndt=\frac 1 {n+1}$

$$y_n = \frac{1}{5}\int_{0}^{1} t^ndt - \frac{1}{5}y_{n+1}$$

$$y_n = \frac{1}{5}\int_{0}^{1} t^ndt - \frac{1}{5} \int_{0}^{1} \frac {t^{n+1}}{t+5}dt$$

$$y_n = \frac{1}{5}\int_{0}^{1} t^n -  \frac {t^{n+1}}{t+5}dt$$

$$y_n =\int_{0}^{1}  \frac {t^n}{t+5}dt$$

Comment: This seems really smooth, I already came up with a reasonable answer by using the idea proposed by @Gribouillis but this is really good too. Seems very logical. Thanks.

Comment: Yw @DavidMerinos the more different answers you get the better...Gribouillis idea is good too.

Answer (score 2):

$y_n + \dfrac{y_{n+1}}{5}= \displaystyle \int_{0}^1\left(\dfrac{t^n}{t+5}+\dfrac{t^{n+1}}{5(t+5)}\right)dt= \displaystyle \int_{0}^1\dfrac{t^n}{5}dt= \dfrac{1}{5(n+1)}$, and this is the desire outcome....